# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

El caso es que tengo 2 `EditText` (tipo numéricos) creados desde `XML`. Agregué un botón para **"Guardar Cambios"** desde el menú cuando los 2 campos estén completos. Escribí código para casos en donde alguno de los 2 campos estén vacíos y funciona. Pero cuando quiero agregar de manera dinámica otros 2 `EditText` mediante un botón y agrego código para representar esos casos en que esté vacío, no me funciona. Es decir, si yo solamente quisiera completar los campos que fueron creados desde `XML`, me salta el error mencionado en el título, pero... si doy clic en el botón **"add"** donde agrego 2 nuevos campos y quiero **"Guardar Cambios"** ahí no tengo problemas. Pero no tendría que funcionar de esa manera.

Alguien sabe cual puede ser el problema?

**Aquí el código en JAVA:**

```
public class cargas_descargas extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton btnAddArt;

/*Definir variables tipo EditText para implementarlas luego en el contenido de sus campos*/


EditText eTcantCarga;
EditText eTcantDescarga;

//Para la nueva tupla creada cuando se requiere añadir nuevos campos

EditText editTextCarga_new_art_xml;
EditText editTextDescarga_new_art_xml;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cargas_descargas);

    btnAddArt = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_art);

    btnAddArt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                AgregarNewArtXML();
            }


        }
    });

    eTcantCarga = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtx_carga);

    eTcantDescarga = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtx_descarga);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

public void AgregarNewArtXML() {

    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrl);

    LinearLayout rootLayoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_vertical);

    //Crear un contenedor (LinearLayout horizontal) programáticamente 

LinearLayout.LayoutParams rootLayoutHorizontalParams = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

final LinearLayout rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico = new LinearLayout(this);


   rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico.setLayoutParams(rootLayoutHorizontalParams);

    rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico.setWeightSum(2);

    ImageButton btnMenosArt = new ImageButton(this);
    btnMenosArt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(45, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btnMenosArt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_menos_art);

    rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico.addView(btnMenosArt);

    //botón para eliminar la fila creada con el ImageButton con icono de "signo menos"

    btnMenosArt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico.getChildCount() > 0) {
                rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico.removeAllViews();
            }

        }
    });

//Creo los 2 EditText de manera dinámica       

    editTextCarga_Programatico = new EditText(this);
    editTextCarga_Programatico.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    editTextCarga_Programatico.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    editTextCarga_Programatico.setHint("Cantidad");
    rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico.addView(editTextCarga_Programatico);



    editTextDescarga_Programatico = new EditText(this);
    editTextDescarga_Programatico.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    editTextDescarga_Programatico.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    editTextDescarga_Programatico.setHint("Cantidad");
    rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico.addView(editTextDescarga_Programatico);


    rootLayoutVertical.addView(rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico);

}


@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cargas_descargas, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();





        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings_carga_descarga) {
            return true;
        }




              //Botón menú para "Guardar cambios"
        if (id == R.id.action_save_tanda) {


     String AuxiliarCantCargas = eTcantCarga.getText().toString();
     String AuxiliarCantDescargas = eTcantDescarga.getText().toString();

 String AuxiliarCantCargas_Programatico = editTextCarga_Programatico.getText().toString();

        String AuxiliarCantDescargas_Programatico = editTextDescarga_Programatico.getText().toString();



                //Estructura repetitiva para duplicar el tiempo de duración del Toast

                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {


                    /*Comienzo de las estructuras selectivas para que cada campo de la fila hech en XML esté completo*/

                    //PRIMER CASO: Estructura selectiva para indicar que todos los campos están vacios


                    if (AuxiliarCantCargas.isEmpty() && AuxiliarCantDescargas.isEmpty()) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error! Los campos están vacíos. Por favor, complete todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
else if (AuxiliarCantCarga.isEmpty()) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error! El campo de carga está vacío. Por favor complete el campo correspondiente con datos válidos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

else if (AuxiliarCantDescarga.isEmpty()) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error! El campo de descarga está vacío. Por favor complete el campo correspondiente con datos válidos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

//USO DE LAS VARIABLES EditText programaticas

else if (AuxiliarCantCargas_Programaticas.isEmpty() && AuxiliarCantDescargas_Programaticas.isEmpty()) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error! Los campos de la nueva fila creada dinamicamente están vacios. Por favor, complete los campos correspondientes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

else if (AuxiliarCantCargas_Programaticas.isEmpty(){

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error! El campo de carga de la fila dinamica está vacío. Por favor, complete el campo correspondiente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

else if (AuxiliarCantDescargas_Programaticas.isEmpty(){

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error! El campo de descarga de la fila dinamica está vacío. Por favor, complete el campo correspondiente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


                    //ULTIMO CASO:

                    else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Los cambios fueron guardados con éxito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();

                    }

                }


            return true;

        }
```

**Código en XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/nueva_cd"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".cargas_descargas"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_cargas_descargas">



<ScrollView

    android:id="@+id/scrl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/layout_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

<ImageButton

                    android:id="@+id/add_art"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_new_art" />


                <EditText

                    android:id="@+id/edtx_carga"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="Cantidad"
                    android:inputType="number" />

                <EditText

                    android:id="@+id/edtx_descarga"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="Cantidad"
                    android:inputType="number" />

            </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout> 

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: podrias publicar el codigo que realizaste ?

Comment: Ahí lo agregué! perdón por la hacerlo engorroso, espero puedas entenderlo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que las instancias de los `EditText` tienen valor null, considera crear estos `EditText` programáticamente al ser llamado el método `onCreate()` de la activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cargas_descargas);

    ... 
    ...

    editTextCarga_Programatico = new EditText(this);
    editTextCarga_Programatico.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    editTextCarga_Programatico.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    editTextCarga_Programatico.setHint("Cantidad");
    rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico.addView(editTextCarga_Programatico);



    editTextDescarga_Programatico = new EditText(this);
    editTextDescarga_Programatico.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    editTextDescarga_Programatico.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    editTextDescarga_Programatico.setHint("Cantidad");
    rootLayoutHorizontalProgramatico.addView(editTextDescarga_Programatico);

    ...
    ...
}
```

de esta forma aseguras que cuando sean usados en otro método ya estan inicializados.

Comment: El problema es que existirán casos donde necesite agregar más filas programaticas con cada clic del boton "add"

Answer (score 0):

Sin necesidad de mirar el codigo, el error que has plasmado indica que intentas obtener el texto de un EditText nulo (sin inicializar).

Vamos que estas haciendo esto:

EditText mEditText;

mEditText.getText();